# What format does the meta_query TIME type require?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

As per title - what format does the TIME type in a meta_query require?

I have a couple of custom fields, `date` and `time` - the aim is to show posts `dated` today and in the future up to the hour before `time`.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => 'date',
        'value'     => date('Y-m-d',strtotime("today")),
        'compare'   => '>=',
        'type'      => 'DATE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'time',
        'value'     => date('H:i', strtotime("now -1 hour")),
        'compare'   => '<=',
        'type'      => 'TIME'
    )
)
```

The `date` part of the query functions fine, but the `time` query doesn't - I suspect something to do with the format.

Answer (score 3):

Date and time format `meta_query` requires the **same format you used when storing the data of the meta fields**. Some times different formats can be compared directly, but most of the time  they aren't. A recommend format to use is MySQL format:

- date format: YYYY-MM-DD (for PHP date functions: Y-m-d)
- time format: HH:MM:SS (for PHP date functions: H:i:s)
- datetime: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (for PHP date functions: Y-m-d H:i:s)

Other recommended format is UNIX timestamp; both can be used directly in database queries with sorting and comparing conditions but if you use MySQL formats you can also recognize the datetime visually.

Additionally, you must note that in `meta_query` ([quoting from codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Accepted_Arguments)):

> The 'type' DATE works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the
>   date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format.

So you have to **store** dates as YYYY-MM-DD if you want to set the `type` argument to `DATE`.

Comment: Thanks - as stated the 'date' part of the query functions correctly. Time is stored as H:i and compared as H:i, but the above query returns no posts.

Comment: You asked what format `meta_query` needs for date and time fields, and that is what I answered. But your real question seems to be anohter. Anyway, I can not see how you are storing the data. Can you post the code, the conditions the post must meet to be selected and one example of post that should be selected but it is not?